# Delete Entry from Front End

Tags: templating

I have this form

```
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">
        <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Listing Title</label>
          <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ entry.title }}">
        </div>
   </form>
```

Is it possible to add a delete button to this form or will it have to be within another form targeting a different end point for entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a single form with a Save button and a Delete button.

The action value is set to `entries/save-entry` by default. However, when the user clicks the Delete button, the action value is changed to `entries/delete-entry` via JavaScript.

I'm using [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/) to accomplish this as follows:

`<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" v-bind:value="'entries/' + actionVal">`

Delete button:

`<button type="submit" value="delete" v-on:click="actionVal = 'delete-entry'">Delete</button>`

In my Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    data: {
        actionVal: 'save-entry'
    },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andrea, is there anyway you can add normal JS/Jquery to this answer?

Comment: I'm actually not very skilled at JavaScript, so perhaps someone else could chime in and I'll update my answer accordingly. Vue.js actually made it easier for me.

Answer (score 4):

Andrea's question is definitely the best way to solve this. However, if you did not want to use Vue in your project, here's how you would solve this in plain JS:

1. Add an `id` to your form and to your hidden action input:

   ```html
   <form id="myForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       {{ csrfInput() }}
       <input id="formAction" type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/save-entry">
       <input type="hidden" name="entryId" value="{{ entry.id }}">

       <div class="form-group">
           <label>Listing Title</label>
           <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" value="{{ entry.title }}">
       </div>
   </form>
   ```
2. Include two buttons with `onclick` attributes:

   ```html
   <button value="save" onclick="submitForm('entries/save-entry')">Save</button>
   <button value="delete" onclick="submitForm('entries/delete-entry')">Delete</button>
   ```
3. Add this script tag to handle the form action swapping:

   ```html
   <script>
       function submitForm(action) {
           document.getElementById('formAction').value = action;
           document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
       }
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

According to the corresponding [controller method](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/controllers/EntriesController.php#L465-L593), there is no way to delete the entry on save. You'd have to call [entries/delete-entry](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master/src/controllers/EntriesController.php#L601-L644) for that.

Of course, if this is really something you want and you're comfortable writing some PHP code, you could programmatically delete the entry before or after save, using a plugin or module.